# How can i get phone number from telegram bot?

Tags: c#, bots, telegram

I like to have inline keyboard and access to contact(requestcontact) and have access to number in c#
I could use request contact in keyboardmarkup but i could not find away to access that number

Comment: give me example code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user press on your `requestContact` button and clicks `"OK"`, he sends his contact in the chat. So, you can process [Update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update).[Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message).[Contact](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#contact).phone_number update.